# What is the significance of the swamp demon's horns?

Tags: demon-slayer

While re-watching Demon Slayer, I noticed that each of the three copies of the swamp demon has a number of horns that seem to correlate to which copy they are:

[image: Picture of Tanjiro facing all three copies of the swamp demon, from left to right, top to bottom, the characters are swamp demon two, swamp demon three, Tanjiro, and finally, swamp demon one.]

Notice here that each copy has a different number of horns ranging from one to three. After reviewing [the wiki on the swamp demon](https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/Swamp_Demon), it seems there is no significance outside of numbering each replica:

> His first body had one horn on its head, the second had two that took the place of its eyebrows, and the third had all three horns

---

Is there any documented significance to the swamp demon's horns, outside of correlating to the replica number?

Comment: Not sure in case of swamp demons or any demons who has horns [but spoilers for season 3 (Armhxb nyfb terj n ubea va frnfba 3. Gurer vf ab ybtvpny ernfba va eryngvba gb gur cybg gung fhttrfgf jul fur unf n ubea.)](https://www.sportskeeda.com/anime/why-nezuko-grow-horn-demon-slayer-explained) So, my not-so-strong guess is that it was just used as aesthetic purpose by the author to depict that it is a demon and not human.